# How to make changes on LineChart

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I tried below and it is not working.

```
<Charting:LineSeries Title="Line_1" Margin="0" 
FontSize="30" Tapped="LineSeries_Tapped" 
FontWeight="SemiBold"   BorderBrush="Red"  
IndependentValuePath="interval" 
DependentValuePath="size" IsSelectionEnabled="True">

 </Charting:Chart>
```

How to

1) change the fontsize for the IndependentValuePath and DependentValuePath? The above is not working.
 2) Change the color of the IndependentValuePath and DependentValuePath? The above is not working.
 3) How to get the value of the IndependentValuePath and DependentValuePath when the line or point of line chart is touched?

------- Edit_2

```
I combine both styles you have provided:

<Charting:Chart 
x:Name="LineChart" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,27,0,0" 
FontWeight="SemiBold"  Width="651" Height="506">

<Charting:LineSeries 
Title="Station1" Margin="0" FontSize="16" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" IndependentValuePath="Q_interval" DependentValuePath="Q_size" IsSelectionEnabled="True">

<Charting:LineSeries.Style>

(1)
  <Style TargetType="Charting:LineSeries">

      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="PolylineStyle">
          <Setter.Value>
             <Style TargetType="Polyline">
             <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
             <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
             </Style>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Charting:LineSeries">
            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
               <Polyline
                   Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}"
                            Stroke="Blue"
                            Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" />
             </Canvas>
         </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>                    
</Charting:LineSeries.Style>

(2)

<Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>                        
<Style TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">                            
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
 </Style>
</Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>

</Charting:LineSeries>              

</Charting:Chart>
```

with (1) and (2) I got the Dot and the stroke.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for `LineSeries` element, the two properties you want to change style are `DependentValueBinding` and `IndependentValueBinding`.

> 1) change the fontsize for the IndependentValuePath and DependentValuePath? The above is not working.

For `IndependentValueBinding` property's style, it is defined by `LineSeries` parent element `Chart`, so directly set the `fontsize` property for the `LineSeris` element will take no effect. Set the `Fontsize` for the chart element will work.

```
<charting:Chart
   x:Name="LineChart"
   Title="Line Chart"
   Margin="70,0" 
   FontSize="30">
```

For `DependentValueBinding` property, it is actually a PolyLine, doesn't have `FontSize` property.

> 2) Change the color of the IndependentValuePath and DependentValuePath? The above is not working.

For the color of `IndependentValueBinding`, it is same with `fontsize` property, just set `Foreground` property for the `Chart` element.
For the color of `DependentValueBinding`, it should change the color of PolyLine which is in ControlTemplate of `LineSeries`. Change the `Stroke` property of `PolyLine` will work.

```
<charting:LineSeries.Style>
    <Style TargetType="charting:LineSeries">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="PolylineStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Polyline">
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LineSeries">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline
                            Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}"
                            Stroke="Red"
                            Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</charting:LineSeries.Style>
```

> 3) How to get the value of the IndependentValuePath and DependentValuePath when the line or point of line chart is touched?

In the tapped event, get the selected item and get the value you bind to the  `IndependentValueBinding` and `DependentValueBinding` properties.

```
if (line1.SelectedItem != null)
{
    NameValueItem seleteditem = line1.SelectedItem as NameValueItem;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(seleteditem.Name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(seleteditem.Value);
}
```

Here is the complete code contain features you want above, please try to set the properties as I mentioned above.

Xaml Code

```
<charting:Chart
    x:Name="LineChart"
    Title="Line Chart"
    Margin="70,0"
    Foreground="Red"
    FontSize="30">
    <charting:LineSeries
        x:Name="line1"
        Title="Population in 2005"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
        IsSelectionEnabled="True"
        Tapped="LineSeries_Tapped">
        <charting:LineSeries.Style>
            <Style TargetType="charting:LineSeries">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="PolylineStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="Polyline">
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LineSeries">
                            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                                <Polyline
                                    Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}"
                                    Stroke="Red"
                                    Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" />
                            </Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </charting:LineSeries.Style>
    </charting:LineSeries>     
</charting:Chart>
```

Code behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private Random _random = new Random();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var items1 = new List<NameValueItem>();
        var items2 = new List<NameValueItem>();
        var items3 = new List<NameValueItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            items1.Add(new NameValueItem { Name = "Name" + i, Value = _random.Next(10, 100) });   
        }
        this.RunIfSelected(this.LineChart, () => ((LineSeries)this.LineChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items1);     

    }


    private void RunIfSelected(UIElement element, Action action)
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }

    private void LineSeries_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (line1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            NameValueItem seleteditem = line1.SelectedItem as NameValueItem;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(seleteditem.Name);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(seleteditem.Value);
        }

    }
}
public class NameValueItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry did not response sooner. I will try it out and get back here. UWP is awesome. I need to work hard on it.

Comment: Please look at my new edit_2. What seems to be the problem in new Chart? How to use the style in my Chart in your New Chart?

Comment: I create another thread to avoid confusion on the same subject but different issue. Hope you can take a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443609/how-to-handle-line-chart-that-keep-expanding-in-both-independent-and-dependentva

Comment: I updated my answer, please just test my completed code. The `FontSize=30`  is what you want. I will look into your new thread. Please ensure you have resolved this thread.

Comment: This <charting:Chart x:Name="LineChart" Title="Line Chart" Margin="70,0"  Foreground="Red"  FontSize="30"> refer to Y-axis.  I want the x-axis fontsize bigger. This <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10" /> refer to the line or stroke size. I want the Point or BreakPoint represented by a DOT. I want this DOT bigger. Thanks

Comment: The fontsize of chart can change the Y axix as well as X axis. The style of Datapoints can be changed by DataPointStyle, for this I will give you a new reply since comment cannot show the code.

Comment: Somehow, the FontSize of chart cannot change the fontsize for x-axis. I set 30, the Y axis get very Big but nothing happen to x axis.The above Edit_2 is the one i used. I will mark it solved. But hope you can find out what I did wrong so I dont repeat this question again. Thanks

Comment: OK, in that case, I need a screenshot about the x axis don't change. Let's end up this thread and go to the new thread you created. I uploaded a demo to github in your new thread. If conveniently please download my demo and try to reproduce the only remain issue about x axis in my demo and updated the demo.

Answer (score 0):

For make the point bigger, you can update the `LineDataPoint` style as follows. Change the `Width` and `Height` property will work. The `Width` and `Height` defined properties of the Ellipse in the control template.

```
<charting:Chart
        x:Name="LineChart"
        Title="Line Chart"
        Margin="70,0"
        Foreground="Red"
        FontSize="10">
        <charting:LineSeries
            x:Name="line1"
            Title="Population in 2005"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True"
            Tapped="LineSeries_Tapped" >
            <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint"> 
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />                      
                </Style>
            </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </charting:LineSeries>
    </charting:Chart>
```