# How to handle Line Chart that keep expanding in both Independent and dependentValues

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How to handle the `Independent` and `dependentValuePath` that keep expanding in every 10 minutes?
Will including `ScrollViewer`  handle this scenario?

Suppose, below is the chart in use:

```
<Charting:LineSeries Title="station1" Margin="0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" IndependentValuePath="Q_interval" DependentValuePath="Q_size" IsSelectionEnabled="True">

  <Charting:LineSeries Title="Terminal 1" Margin="10" FontSize="16" Foreground="Blue"  FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Purple" BorderBrush="Red"  IndependentValuePath="Q_interval" DependentValuePath="Q_size" IsSelectionEnabled="True">
    <Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
      <Style TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
      </Style>
    </Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
  </Charting:LineSeries>
</Charting:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to handle the Independent and dependentValuePath that keep expanding in every 10 minutes.

You can use a [DispatherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) to control the `independent` and `dependent` value every 10 minutes.

> Is including ScrollViewer will handle this scenario?

`LineChat` in WinRTXamlToolKit can arrange the axis automatically, you don't need to let a ScrollViewer handle it.

Here is the completed demo about expanding the `independent` and `dependent` every 2 seconds.

XAML Code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <charting:Chart
        x:Name="LineChart"
        Title="Line Chart"
        Margin="70,0"
        Foreground="Red"
        FontSize="10">
        <charting:LineSeries
            x:Name="line1"
            Title="Population in 2005"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </charting:Chart>
```

Code behind,

```
public sealed partial class NewChart : Page
{
    private Random _random = new Random();
    private EventThrottler _updateThrottler = new EventThrottler();
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private int total = 1;
    public NewChart()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };
        _timer.Tick += AddlineChat;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void AddlineChat(object sender, object e)
    {
        total += 1;
        _updateThrottler.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                this.UpdateCharts(total);
                sw.Stop();
                await Task.Delay(sw.Elapsed);
            });
    }

    private void RunIfSelected(UIElement element, Action action)
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
    private void UpdateCharts(int n)
    {
        var items1 = new List<NameValueItem>();
        var items2 = new List<NameValueItem>();
        var items3 = new List<NameValueItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            items1.Add(new NameValueItem { Name = "Name" + i, Value = _random.Next(10, 100) });
        }
        this.RunIfSelected(this.LineChart, () => ((LineSeries)this.LineChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = items1);
    }
}

public class NameValueItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Shared my demo to GitHub, please see [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CXamlToolKit).

Comment: downloaded the app. I had some problems to run the app as it is empty when I used vs2015 Community ver to open it. I can see the files in the folder but VS2015 say it is unavailable. So, I create a project to use your file. But which one I need to download? WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP  or any version can be used? or use WinRTXamlToolkite.Control.DataVisualization.Windows for your app.

Comment: Both [WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows 10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit) and [WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.Controls.DataVisualization) are needed.

Comment: My project require 14393 SDK. Try it ,if you still cannot run, tell me the SDK build you are using.

Comment: when I installed both WinRT XAML Toolkit.UWP and WinRTXamlToolKit.DataVisualization, the Compiler complained and I need to remove WinRTXamlToolKit.UWP.  After remove, it compiled and run. I have created a project using all your files. Can you confirm why the compiler required me to remove WinRTXamlToolKit.UWP , it create conflict! I am Using VS2015 Community version.

Comment: I used Nuget package Manager in VS to install.

Comment: The [WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows 10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/) contains [WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/). You only need one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123144/discussion-between-sunteen-msft-and-milkbottle).